# Reducer expected to be a function REDUX

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to practice a little bit around with redux ducks way of arranging the files, I started a practice, but I am getting the error on the title which I do not know where it is coming from, as if I try to implement in any other ways I get no problem with the reducers, so the reducers are just fine, but with this set up it does not seem to work:
this is my store.js:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";

import userReducer from "./userReducer"; // se le puede poner el nombre que quera porque estamos exportando como default solo esa funcion
import charsReducer, { getCharsAction } from "./charsReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  characters: charsReducer
});

// export const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());

export default function generateStore() {
  //toma como primer argumento el reducer, segundo el estado inicial, y tercero el middleware
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools);
  getCharsAction()(store.dispatch, store.getState); // traemos los personajes por primera vez
  return store;
}
```

and this is the index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import generateStore from "./redux/store";

const store = generateStore();

const WithRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);

const WithStore = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <WithRouter />
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<WithStore />, document.getElementById("root"));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

userReducer.js:

```
//PATRON DE DISEÑO REDUX DUCK
const initialState = {
  loggedIn: false
};
//constants
const LOGIN = "LOGIN";
//reducer
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
    // return 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
} //el reducer esta siempre escuchando hasta que hagas una accion que coincida con las definidas

//actions
```

charsReducer.js:

```
import axios from "axios";
//constants
const initialState = {
  fetching: false,
  chars: [],
  currentChar: {}
};
const API_URL = "https://rickyandmortyapi.com/api/character";
const GET_CHARACTERS = "GET_CHARACTERS";
const GET_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS = "GET_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS";
const GET_CHARACTERS_ERROR = "GET_CHARACTERS_ERROR";

//reducers
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CHARACTERS:
    case GET_CHARACTERS_ERROR:
    case GET_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, array: action.payload }; // EN ESTE MOMENTO SE GUARDAN EN EL STORE, devuelve todo lo que tenias en el state y en el array mete ademas lo que le llaga por payload(los personajes)
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
//actions(thunks)
export const getCharsAction = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  return axios.get(API_URL).then(res => {
    dispatch({ type: GET_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS, payload: res.data.results });
  });
};
```

here is the output I am getting:

```
×
Error: Expected the reducer to be a function.
▶ 8 stack frames were collapsed.
generateStore
C:/Users/anton/desktop/Curso-React-Redux-GraphQL-master/src/redux/store.js:16
  13 | 
  14 | export default function generateStore() {
  15 |   //toma como primer argumento el reducer, segundo el estado inicial, y tercero el middleware
> 16 |   const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools);
  17 |   getCharsAction()(store.dispatch, store.getState); // traemos los personajes por primera vez
  18 |   return store;
  19 | }
View compiled
Module../src/index.js
C:/Users/anton/desktop/Curso-React-Redux-GraphQL-master/src/index.js:11
   8 | import { Provider } from "react-redux";
   9 | import generateStore from "./redux/store";
  10 | 
> 11 | const store = generateStore();
  12 | 
  13 | const WithRouter = () => (
  14 |   <BrowserRouter>
View compiled
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/anton/desktop/Curso-React-Redux-GraphQL-master/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/Users/anton/desktop/Curso-React-Redux-GraphQL-master/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
1
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1141:18
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/anton/desktop/Curso-React-Redux-GraphQL-master/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
C:/Users/anton/desktop/Curso-React-Redux-GraphQL-master/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 
View compiled
Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
C:/Users/anton/desktop/Curso-React-Redux-GraphQL-master/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
View compiled
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:65
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
```

Comment: Please add code for `userReducer` and `charsReducer`

Comment: Done!, but I do not think the reducers are the problem as without changin those files if I change the setup in the index and the store to a non-duck set up it works with those same reducers... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem occurs here : Instead of passing reference of composeWithDevTools pass composeWithDevTools() this will return required values for store

```
 const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools);

 change it to 

 const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());
```

Comment: let me know if you still have any problems

Comment: done! sorry but I did not know that, I am pretty new here, I will do from now on as I have not done it in my previous questions...

Comment: :) it will boost over self to help as much as posible